# Unable to get the selected values on Dialog while using ContextMenu with Datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu, facelets

I have a requirement where I want the user to move the datatable rows up and down.I thought Context Menu would come handy as there would be a Move up and Move down menu item .For this I tried implementing the context Menu for datatable example from Primefaces Showcase. However I am not getting the selected values from the datatable rows to be displayed on the dialog.

Please find the below code:

```
 <p:contextMenu for="availableCars">
        <p:menuitem value="View" update="display" icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"/> 
        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:dataTable id="availableCars" var="car" value="#{RequestBean.formFields}" rowKey="#{car.car_group}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{RequestBean.selectedField}">
        <p:column headerText="Field Label">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.car_label}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Field Group">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.car_group}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Field Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.car_name}" />
        </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"
          width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" id="dialog">
         <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
        <h:outputText value="Car label:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{RequestBean.selectedField.car_label}" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <h:outputText value="car Group" />
        <h:outputText value="#{RequestBean.selectedField.car_group}" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <h:outputText value="Car Name:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{RequestBean.selectedField.car_name}" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
N.B: I am using PF 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the selection doesn't get sent using ajax - you need to set the `onRowSelectUpdate` attribute on the data table.

From Primefaces documentation:

> In both single and multiple selection options described before, enclosing form needs to be submitted 
>   by user so that the selections would be processed and set to the selection value reference. If you’d 
>   like to execute custom logic whenever the row is selected instantly bind a rowSelectListeneror or define onRowSelectUpdate option.

Comment: Thanks @dratewka . It works. Additionally I have used rowSelectListener="#{RequestBean.onCarSelect}" to set the data to selectedField.